# Symfony2 return CrossDomain header on every response

Tags: php, symfony, cross-domain, cors

Is there a way to configure my app to return a specific header with every response?

I'm developing a restful api and I need to support Cross Domain requests, I've been looking at CORS but it needs for me to return a header like this on every response:

- Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' true
- Access-Control-Allow-Origin' **Any Client**
- Access-Control-Allow-Methods 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS'
- Access-Control-Allow-Headers, 'X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version,  - -  Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version'

Comment: $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'Any Client');

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom `ResponseListener` and set the header for each response:

```
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterResponseEvent;

class ResponseListener
{
    public function onKernelResponse(FilterResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();

        // only do something on some situations
        if (false === strpos($request->headers->get('Foobar'), 'barfoo')) {
            return;
        }

        // set the custom header of the response
        $event->getResponse()->headers->set('Acme', 'demo');
    }
}
```

Then declare the listener as a service:

```
# app/config/config.yml
services:
    kernel.listener.your_listener_name:
        class: Acme\DemoBundle\EventListener\ResponseListener
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.response, method: onKernelResponse }
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html